# Setting alternative records true if its even count else leave last record

Tags: c#

I have an attendance list like this.

**problem:** I need to set `In` and `Out` alternatively. but if I have only 3 records then I need to set 0 record In true. 1 record out is true. and 3 record has is both `In` `Out` is `false`. I tried like this its working fine. but I was checking is there any better way

```
ObservableCollection<EmployeeAttandance> attendancesPerDay = new ObservableCollection<EmployeeAttandance>();
if (attendancesPerDay.Count % 2 == 0)
{
    int counter = 0;
    foreach (var attendance in attendancesPerDay)
    {
        if (counter % 2 == 0)
            attendance.In = true;
        else
            attendance.Out = true;
        counter++;
    }
}
else
{
    int counter = 0;
    foreach (var attendance in attendancesPerDay)
    {
        if (attendancesPerDay.IndexOf(attendance) == attendancesPerDay.Count - 1)
            continue;
        if (counter % 2 == 0)
            attendance.In = true;
        else
            attendance.Out = true;
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful for the review if the source of entire function was in the question. It would be even more helpful if the entire class and the definition of attendance was included in the question. We need more context.

Comment: @pacmaninbw the class big

Answer (score 1):

In the else clause it might be better to have an `if` statement with a block of code than a `continue` statement:

```
    foreach (var attendance in attendancesPerDay)
    {
        if (attendancesPerDay.IndexOf(attendance) != attendancesPerDay.Count - 1)
        {
            if (counter % 2 == 0)
                attendance.In = true;
            else
                attendance.Out = true;
            counter++;
        }
    }
```

The logic is basically the same and it is easier to see the scope of the code.

To reduce the repetition of the code there could be a short function that takes 2 parameters, `counter` and `attendance` and performs the assignment.

As a personal choice I prefer to specify the real type in a `foreach` loop because it is self documenting, the user of `var` hides too much.

Comment: `In` should have `out` lets say i have 4 records then no problem `0 is in= true` `1 is out=true`` 2 in = true` `3 out =true done`. in case I got only 3 records then` 0 in =true 1 out =true 2 both in and out is false`

Comment: so this thing don`t set anything for last record always